Issue with training model on Kaggle GPU - only one GPU working
I'm currently trying to train a model on Kaggle using GPU resources, but it seems that only one GPU is being utilized instead of multiple. I'm using the following training code:
# Step 1: Install the required packages
#!pip install ultralytics xmltodict albumentations torch torchvision torchaudio

# Step 5: Train the YOLO model
import os
import torch
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Set WANDB_MODE to 'dryrun' to disable WanDB logging
os.environ['WANDB_MODE'] = 'dryrun'

# Set up device for multiple GPUs
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = YOLO('yolov8x.pt')  # load a pretrained YOLOv8 model

# Check if multiple GPUs are available
if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print(f"Using {torch.cuda.device_count()} GPUs")
    model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model, device_ids=list(range(torch.cuda.device_count()))).to(device)
else:
    model = model.to(device)

# Define the training configuration
data_yaml = """
train: /../images/train_combined_data
val:   /../images/val
test:  /../images/test
nc: 1
names: ['Hotspot']
"""

with open('data.yaml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data_yaml)

# Train the model
model.train(
    data='data.yaml',
    epochs=50,  # Total number of training epochs
    batch=16,  
    imgsz=640,  # Target image size for training
    device='cuda'
)


I've checked Kaggle's documentation and it should support multiple GPUs for training. Is there something specific I need to add to my code to enable multi-GPU training, or is there a setting on Kaggle that I might have missed?
Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
How can I use both the gpus?

You can try to list the available device numbers to use them instead of device='cuda' in your training parameters. device: # (int | str | list, optional) device to run on, i.e. cuda device=0 or device=0,1,2,3 or device=cpu.  https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/blob/main/ultralytics/cfg/default.yaml
